# How to get handler to close fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-handler

When the user clicks the okay button, it sends information from the form they filled out to the database. The handler will then add the user into the database and if the process is successful then I want the fragment to close.

From the suggestions on similar questions I tried,

`finish()`,

`MyActivity.this.finish()`,

`getActivity().getFragmentManager().popBackStack();`.

I know the information being sent is successful because I checked the database but the fragment view won't close.

```
if(success.equals("1"))
{
  finish();
}
```

I want the fragment to finish so that the MainActivty's onCreate will run again.

```
public class Add extends Activity {

private Fragment fragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hello);


    fragment = new FirstFragment();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
    }
}


public static class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
    private static EditText first;
    private static EditText last;
    private static Button okay;

    public FirstFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Add a = new Add();
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_student,
                container, false);
        first= (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.first);
        last= (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.last);
        okay = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.okay);
        okay.setOnClickListener(a.new MyOnClickListener());
        return rootView;
    }
}


public class MyOnClickListener implements OnClickListener 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        ...
        //database
    }
}


final Handler handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        switch(msg.what){
        case DatabaseController.OKAY:
        {
            try{
                JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject((String) msg.obj);
                String success = json_data.getString("success");

                if(success.equals("1"))
                {
                    //finish();             
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new JSONException("Input failed");
                }
            }catch(JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        }
    }
};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't close a fragment, you can only remove it, or close the containing Activity.

To remove the fragment try:

```
getActivity().getFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .remove(this)
    .commit();
```

Or you can close the containing Activity with:

```
getActivity().finish();
```

edit: as you defined the Handler in the Activity and not in the Fragment what I previously assumed, the first code should be changed like this:

```
getFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .remove(fragment)
    .commit();
```

This will remove the Fragment from the Activity, but it will not re-call the onCreate method, as your Activity stays the same as was before. If you want to run the onCreate of your Activity again you have to start your Activity again (with startActivity()/startActivityForResult) and finish the currently running instance.

Comment: But when I used getActivity() it says "The method getActivity() is undefined for the type new Handler(){}".

Comment: Where do you have your Handler class defined?

Comment: I tried it but nothing happens. I debugged it and it seems the handler is not running the code yet. Why is that?

Comment: Your code looks good to me, the only thing I can think of is that you're not sending the message to the Handler after you finished the database operations.

Comment: Could you give me an example of what you mean by not sending the message to the Handler?